# How to create multiple data members for a class in python using a loop..?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I was trying to create multiple data members for a class in python uisng the for loop but seems like python creates just a single data member for each loop iteration. I am sure the way am doing it is correct or not but if any of you get my motive and can help then please do. I think `setitem` could be a solution but i don't know how?

```py
class VectorNd:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.length = 0
        self.member_names = kwargs.keys()
        for (i,j) in kwargs.items():
            self.i = j
    
    def __str__(self):
        ret_str = ''
        print(self.member_names)
        for i in self.member_names:
            ret_str += f'({self.i}{i}) +'
        return ret_str[:-2]

obj = VectorNd(i=1,j=2,k=3,l=5)
print(obj.i)
```

Output:
`5`

I wish to create new data members each time the loop is iterated instead of creating a single `self.i` data member.

Comment: `self.i = j` => `setattr(self, i, j)`. Otherwise, you just set the same attribute `i` all over again. Likely, in `__str__` it should be `getattr(self, i)`

Comment: You can just use `vars(self).update(kwargs)` here.